# Invalid volume specification error when bulding container in https

Tags: docker, https, volume, specifications

I'm quite new with Docker and I am having problem to run containers in https mode. I am following these instructions: https://github.com/dotnet/dotnet-docker/blob/main/samples/run-aspnetcore-https-development.md
but when I try the docker run instruction I receive the following message error:

Error response from daemon: invalid volume specification: 'C:\Users\2590\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:rw'

I understand that:

- host directory in my computer is: C:\Users\2590\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\UserSecrets\
- container directory is: /root/.microsoft/usersecrets

The host directory exists, so I think the problem must be in the container directory. But I suppose docker builds that /root/.microsoft/usersecrets for me, right?

I am using Virtual Studio 2022 Community and Windows 11.

How can I solve this problem? I know there are people asking the same question, but the answer they receive doesn't solve my issue. Thank you!

PD: I try to follow also this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lcaDDxJv260, but still having same problem.